# Using the REST API in Apache Airflow Helm Chart

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

I'm running Apache Airflow, built off of the Helm chart, and I'd like to use the REST Api to run dags. However when I make a request, I get a  401 Unauthenticated error.

I know this is due to the auth_backends not being set up properly. My question is what should I add to the Helm chart's value.yaml file in order for it to initialize the auth_backends in the config? The Airflow docs seem outdated on this point.

Here is my current values.yaml file:

```
executor: CeleryExecutor
dags:
  persistence:
    enabled: true
    existing-claim: task-pv-claim
  gitSync:
    enabled: false
redis: 
  enabled: true
scheduler:
  extraInitContainers:
  - name: fix-dags-permissions
    image: busybox
    command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 50000:0 /opt/airflow/dags/" ]
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 0
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /opt/airflow/dags/
        name: dags
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

If you are making a request using basic auth (passing something like `--user "admin:admin"`). You should activate basic auth. This is done [adding an extra env](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/adding-connections-and-variables.html):

```
extraEnv: |
  - name: AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS
    value: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
```